# Retrieve timezone details of remote server

Tags: java, testing, automated-tests

I have tests where I want to performs some tests around server date/time, hence I want to retrieve timezone details of the server. My tests run on a client with different time zone most of the time hence using client timezone does not help. Could you please let us know how this can be achieved through Java APIs?

Answer (score 0):

There's not Java API for that. You have to have a server program waiting on another PC knowing how to service your particular request. One thing you can do this e.g. with ssh (Java has [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) library allowing to do that.

```
$ ssh your.host.name.here date +%Z
EST
```

Another option is to write your custom java app exposing just the timezone over http and run it on the system of your interest.

Answer (score 0):

```
private String getServerTimeZoneDisplayName()
{
final TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
final boolean daylight = timeZone.inDaylightTime(new Date());
final Locale locale = servletRequest.getLocale();
return timeZone.getDisplayName(daylight, TimeZone.LONG, locale);
}
```